# Setting icon className in leaflet when using Svelte doesn't have any effect

Tags: css, leaflet, svelte

I'm using `leaflet` maps in conjunction with Svelte and have the problem that setting the `className` property of an `Icon` (L.Icon) that is used for a `Marker` (L.marker) doesn't have any effect. My code works fine without Svelte, so I assume that the source of the problem is the dynamic generation of a css class. My (abbreviated) code looks like this:

```
    var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: "./svg/My-Icon.svg",
        iconSize: [48, 48],
        iconAnchor: [24, 32],
        className: "svgShadow",
    });
    ...
    marker = L.marker(
        geoJsonPoint.geometry.coordinates.reverse(),
        {
            icon: myIcon ,
            name: "Here is some text"
        }).addTo(map);


    <!-- Styles go at the bottom of the file with Svelte -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .svgShadow {
            filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.5));
        }
    </style>
```

Inspecting the element in the browser even shows that the class name is set for the `img` element contained in the marker, but it doesn't have any effect. Again, this works **without** Svelte in a static HTML page. **With** Svelte I can only find a dynamically generated css class containing the style definition for `.svgShadow` that isn't applied, but how can I make this work **with** leaflet and Svelte? Unfortunately I also can't set styles directly with the leaflet icon as only `className` is exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles are scoped by default. If the elements are not created *directly* as part of the markup, they will not have the necessary classes that are added to the styles.

You can e.g. use `:global(.svgShadow) { ...` to circumvent this.

(Note that this of course will apply the the styles everywhere, even outside the current component.)